# java give a string to running process exe

Tags: java, process, centos, overpass-api

I was tried to get OSM data from my local overpass API. There are four steps to get OSM data.

1. run the binary file  `/srv/osm3s/bin/osm3s_query`
2. once the osm3s_query is running, you'll see this message`encoding remark: Please enter your query and terminate it with CTRL+D.`
3. input your query `<query type="node"><bbox-query n="51.0" s="50.9" w="6.9" e="7.0"/><has-kv k="amenity" v="pub"/></query><print/>`
4. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and get the OSM results

my code as below:

```
try
    {            
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("/srv/osm3s/bin/osm3s_query");
        InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
```

The process will hang on step 2 after shown the message `encoding remark: Please enter your query and terminate it with CTRL+D.`. I have no idea how to give the process the query string.

Anybody has some idea?

Comment: You have the process's input stream. You can also get the output stream.

Comment: You should write to the output stream your query.

Comment: According to the Javadoc for `Process`: "As of 1.5, ProcessBuilder.start() is the preferred way to create a Process."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OutputStreamWriter output = proc.getOutputStream();
output.write(yourQuery);
output.write(4); // that's ctrl-d
output.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly -- this is a pretty fragile way to interact with the Overpass API. Since Overpass is an XML-over-HTTP API, and Java has lots of XML and HTTP libraries, there are plenty of ways to do it in native Java. OpenStreetMap provides examples - for example http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Java_Access_Example

This is probably easier, and certainly more robust, than calling an external command.

There are also higher level Java libraries: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

---

For the general case of running a process, writing to its stdin and reading from its stdout, since Java 1.5 it's best to use `ProcessBuilder` to create your `Process`.

Once you have a process, you can use `getInputStream()`, `getOutputSteam()` and `getErrorStream()` to get the relevant streams (in the builder, if you like, you can make stderr go to stdout).

It's possible to get into a deadlock when reading and writing these streams - in many situations you'll need to either use non-blocking IO classes or create separate threads for reading and writing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Due to some special reasons, query via HTTP is not allow. I took your advice ` ProcessBuilder.start()` and `getOutputSteam()`.